# Django Graphene - Pass info.context to a decorator on a Query or a Mutation

Tags: django, graphene-python

I am trying to pass a resolve function in a Query to a custom decorator. While **kwargs are getting passed to the decorator function, it looks like the info object is not getting passed. When I try to read the info in the decorator I get a value of None. Without the decorator, I am able to read the info object, directly in the resolve function.

Please note the decorator shown below is a test code to read the info object and does not serve any other purpose. I understand there are defined decorators available in the django/graphene framework, but I'd like to understand how to pass the info object correctly to a decorator, for custom code.

Thanks!

**Query**

class Query(object):

```
all_users = graphene.List(UserNode)
all_roles = graphene.List(UserRoleNode)

@authenticate_role
def resolve_all_users(self,info,*args,**kwargs):
    return User.objects.all()
```

**Decorator**

```
def authenticate_role(func):
   def wrap(info, *args, **kwargs):
      print (info)
      print(kwargs.get('id'))
      auth_header = info.context.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
      print (auth_header)
   return wrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying your example code so it will run without external dependencies (and actually wrap the function), it seems to me your arguments at run time might just not be what you're expecting.

Since you're including `self`, this looks like it's a method; because of that, `self` will be the first argument passed to your wrapper, which appears to expect that to be `info`.

```
def authenticate_role(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

class Test(object):
    @authenticate_role
    def resolve_all_users(self, info, *args, **kwargs):
        print("In r_a_u:", info)

Test().resolve_all_users("info", "ar", "gs", a="b", c="d")
# (<__main__.Test object at 0x...>, 'info', 'ar', 'gs')
# {'c': 'd', 'a': 'b'}
# In r_a_u: info
```

It's hard to say which part of this should be relevant, since your example doesn't really make it clear what your code actually looks like and what your results are, but it should put you on the right track.